# Block Chrome accessing modem

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I need to run Chrome offline from the command line.
I have an Ubuntu box with a GPRS modem attached using  a PPP connection to talk to the world. However, every time I run Chrome it starts down/uploading data via the PPP connection. This is proving expensive as its on a mobile newtwork.( 1Mb per hour ish)  I just want Chrome to boot and run using local assets. I could turn the PPP off when I enter Chrome, but I need the PPP on 24/7 to monitor incoming requests.
Any Ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps use proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of.

1: Run Chrome as a user that is part of a `no-internet` group.

```
groupadd no-internet
usermod -a -G no-internet YourUserName
```

create a file `/usr/local/bin/no-internet` with

```
#!/bin/bash
sg no-internet "$@"
```

and create an `iptables`-rule

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP
```

You could add some `allow`-rules for your local LAN.

Then with `no-internet google-chrome`, you should get Chrome without Internet access.

2: Install a squid-proxy and tell Chrome to use that proxy. You can of course also use ngnix or other types, it's just that I have more experience with squid and I think it is the easiest to configure.

A third option would be to use a different browser. Chrome needs a lot of Internet connection to function properly (determine whether the version is up-to-date, get CRLs etc.). Firefox seems to use the Internet less, and you could even look at Dillo.